# Redirect from HttpGet Action Method to HttpPost Action Method with parameters in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, redirect

I want to redirect from an ASP.NET Core `HttpGet` action method to `HttpPost` action method and send the parameters from the `Get` action to `Post` action - is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core, you cannot directly redirect from an HTTP GET action to an HTTP POST action and pass parameters during the redirect. However, you can achieve a similar result by using TempData or Session to store the data temporarily between the GET and POST requests.